# Is there a length limit for array in surrealdb?

Tags: surrealdb

Is there a number limit for array? for example i create a too large array in a table.
What is the cost of adding an element to an array?

I hope there is no limit to length of array in surrealdb. no extra cost for adding a item to array

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard limit to the array size from our side.

And doing CRUD with recordIDs has near-constant performance regardless of scale because you don't need to do table scans.

You can find more information about the performance at scale in these two blog posts:

- https://surrealdb.com/blog/the-life-changing-magic-of-surrealdb-record-ids
- https://surrealdb.com/blog/surrealdb-scalability